# "javascript:" on browser won't change the type

Tags: javascript, browser

look at this code,

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
function change()
{
 document.getElementById("myInput").type="text";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout('change()',2000);">
<input type = "button" id="myInput">
</body>
</html>
```

now, my button becomes text box after 2 seconds.. Iam happy! 
Why not the same happens when i try to do from the browser (i tested in IE6 & Chrome) using

`javascript:document.getElementById("myInput").type="text"`

different browsers behave in different way... 
when i tried `javascript:document.getElementById("myInput").value="myNewValue"`, IE6 changes the value, but chrome doesn't..

Why is this "javascript:" behaving like this ?

Comment: where are you putting the javascript:... code? Are you typing that into the address bar, an href?

Comment: directly in address bar!, It works when i put in href... it doesn't work when i put it in addressbar.

Comment: Is there a reason you actually need this to work from the address bar? I mean I can see the curiosity, but modern browsers all have better tools to test this sort of thing. Even IE8 lets you execute javascript in the developer console.

Comment: Not at all. Just curiosity! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("myInput").setAttribute('type','text');
```

I'm not sure why it behaves like that, I think that it is because setting a value returns the value, and returning a string results in a page displaying that string, like:

```
javascript:"test";
```

Will open a page with 'test'., Using setAttribute() returns nothing.

Comment: Thanks.! That explains the behavior.!

Comment: Also look into the void() function, which does an equivalent thing